# Is Zoro stronger than Luffy?

Tags: one-piece

When watching *One Piece*, I sometimes feel as though Zoro is more powerful than Luffy, even though he don't have a Devil Fruit power.

Is Zoro stronger than Luffy?

Comment: there is no objective answer to this and Oda hasn't said anything. This question should probably be closed as opinion-based. My guess though is that Luffy is overall stronger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is: as of chapter 1037, no.

Physically, Zoro is stronger than Luffy, that is if Luffy does not use his DF powers and Zoro does not use his swords. That is to say, in a fair arm-wrestling match, Zoro will win.

But once DF is involved, the answer becomes quite complex. In East Blue, Luffy being stronger than Zoro is extremely debatable. In fact, till Luffy showed his Gears, Zoro and Luffy were comparable in power. But once the Gears started, we can see Luffy starting to leapfrog Zoro in terms of fighting.

Post-time-skip, it was definitive that Luffy was stronger because he can freely control his COC Haki and Zoro didn't even know he could use it till Zoro v Kaido. And not to mention G4 gives Luffy a lot more mobility which Zoro lacks as an evident by the King v Zoro fight. Thus making it even more difficult for Zoro.

Luffy v Zoro will be an intense fight. But Luffy will be able to beat Zoro at the end once he goes to G4.

In fact, Wano makes Zoro and Sanji more comparable in power levels than Luffy and Zoro ever were.

Answer (score -1):

About physical factors: strength, speed, endurance; they are really close

About Haki: they have the 3 forms, but Luffy has the advantage of better control

DF: no surprise here

X factor: the big weakness of Luffy, except for massive water, is a weapon able to cut and Zoro is a swordsman

For me, they are really close but there is an advantage to Luffy.

Comment: Welcome to the Q&A site Anime & Manga Stack Exchange. While we appreciate anyone's contribution, note that pure opinion/speculative answer is discouraged. Instead, consider [edit]ing and trying to back up the answer by providing supporting sources/references. Thank you.

Comment: Also, we have [a strict policy to disclose the affiliation on the post directly](https://anime.stackexchange.com/help/referencing).